# Hibernate Criteria Query select where clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, criteriaquery

```
person:

id | owner_email               | firstname | lastname 
----+-------------+-----------+----------
 44 | john@gmail.com           | john       | wood
 45 | alex@gamil.com           | alex       | greenwood
 49 | peter@gamil.com          | peter      | blacksmith
 50 | john@gmail.com           | lee        | wu
 51 | john@gmail.com           | jane       | li
```

i am making a spring hibernate web application, 
i have a table like above. 
what i m trying to get is something like:

```
select * from person where owner_email='john@gmail.com'
```

so the method will return me list of person objects related to john@gmail.com

here is my query code but doesnt work...

```
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;


    @Transactional
    public List<Person> listPerson() {
        CriteriaQuery<Person> c = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Person.class);
        Root<Person> from = c.from(Person.class);
        c.multiselect(from.get("owner_email"));
        c.orderBy(em.getCriteriaBuilder().asc(from.get("firstname")));
        return em.createQuery(c).getResultList();
    }
```

here is the error i get....

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.example.model.Person] [select new com.example.model.Person(generatedAlias0.owner_email) from com.example.model.Person as generatedAlias0]
```

please help me with code example thanks...

Comment: Your question is very unclear.If you want a list of persons, why does your method return a List<PrayTimes> and not a List<Person>? If you want to select from  theperson table, why do you use c.from(PrayTimes.class) and not c.from(Person.clas)? If you want to add a predicate on the owner_email, why don't you add one? The code doesn't match at all with what your description says. Finally, why in hell do you use criteria instead of a damn simple JPQL query: `select p from Person p where p.ownerEmail = :email`.

Comment: And now you changed the code, but the error doesn't match with the code.

Comment: copied wrong code,,, just edit it

Comment: so where exactly do i put sql query ?

Comment: Also none of what you have here is Hibernate-specific; you're using all JPA stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@PersistenceContext 
EntityManager em;

@Transactional 
public List<Person> listPerson() { 
    CriteriaQuery<Person> c = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Person.class); 
    Root<Person> from = c.from(Person.class); 

    c.select(from);
    c.where(em.getCriteriaBuilder().equal(from.get("owner_email"),"john@gmail.com")); // <- this will add the restriction. 

    c.orderBy(em.getCriteriaBuilder().asc(from.get("firstname"))); 
    return em.createQuery(c).getResultList(); 
}
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to format your code. This answer could be better if you updated it to draw attention to the important parts of the code you've changed.

Comment: @JasonC Thanx! I'm struggling with the wiki syntax in the android app.

Comment: Suggestion: I would set up a `builder` variable instead of calling `em.getCriteriaBuilder()` multiple times.